# An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable'

Tags: python, databricks, user-defined-functions

```
def checkAuxiliary(telemetryData, auxiliaryThreshold):
  for telemetryDataElement in telemetryData :
    if telemetryDataElement.pi == "137" and  int(float(telemetryDataElement.v)) >= int(auxiliaryThreshold) :
      return 1
  return 0
spark.udf.register("checkAuxiliary", checkAuxiliary)
```

when I run my write stream query, I got this error:

An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable'

Comment: What is 'telemetryData' here? is it an iterable object? For ex: List, Array?

Comment: Also, what is your question even? Please take the [tour] and read [ask]! Further, check out https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+TypeError+NoneType.